# Hyperlink is not working in my chrome extension

Tags: hyperlink, google-chrome-extension

I have made a chrome extension where user login and its favorite shops are being displayed, now I want to user to be log out when it will click on log out button, I am calling a javascript function but it is not working.

Logout Code:

```
<a href='#' onclick='DeleteCookies('memberid');'>Logout</a>
```

When I debug it in chrome editor then it says
Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy.

Besides this I was trying to user should go to main website when he will click on an image but that link was also not working, all is that hyperlinks are not working.

What should I do to resolve this? can any one tell me its solution? i will be very thankful to him.

Comment: It's fully explained in the documentation, see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html. You can't use inline events when manifest version 2 is active.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you cannot use inline script in extensions. Give an 'id' to your link and in a separate javascript file write on click function for that 'id' and include this javascript file in your html head section.